# Sitefinity upgrade from 8.2 to 12.2 - Build succeeded but while running the project it gets stuck in between and nothing seems to be happening

Tags: content-management-system, upgrade, sitefinity, sitefinity-8

I was trying to upgrade Sitefinity from 8.2 to 12.2 using the Sitefinity upgrade document. https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/122/upgrade-from-sitefinity-cms-8.0-and-below

Steps followed :

1. Uninstalled the old version from Nuget
2. Changed the .Net framework to 4.7.2
3. Reinstall all packages
4. Added few properties in assemblyinfo.cs
5. Installed Sitefinity 12.2
6. Uninstalled Thunder, Dropbox libraries, Telerik.Sitefinity.MobileAppBuilder, Telerik.Sitefinity.DAM
   Telerik.Sitefinity.EverliveConnector

Now the build is successful but it is getting stuck. Need some help with this. Is it ok to directly upgrade from 8.2 to 12.2 or upgrade from 8.2 to 10 and from 10 to 12.2? Which approach is preferred?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: should be ok to upgrade from 8.2 to 12.2 directly. Are there any errors in the logs? Is the cpu of the w3wp process doing anything or is it idle? what about the sql server? Maybe the database is too big and the upgrade process would take some time

Comment: DB Size is 2 GB only. In the task manager, it seems to change CPU utilization. I am attaching one more image where it is getting stuck.

Comment: check the log files

Comment: Type : System.ArgumentException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=
Message : Value of 'null' is not valid for 'stream'.
Source : System.Drawing
Help link : 
ParamName : 
Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite : System.Drawing.Image FromStream(System.IO.Stream, Boolean, Boolean)

Comment: Saw this error in the error logs.

Comment: I think its some where while initializing library.Any suggestions. Below is from the log: 
   at Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Pages.PageTemplateHelper.UpdateDefaultTemplateImages(PageManager pageManager, LibrariesManager librariesManager, Album album)
   at Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Libraries.LibrariesModule.Upgrade(SiteInitializer initializer, Version upgradeFrom)
   at Telerik.Sitefinity.Services.ModuleBase.Install(SiteInitializer initializer, Version upgradeFrom)
   at Telerik.Sitefinity.Services.SystemManager.InitializeModule 
will deactivating the module help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error messages in the comments of your post:

```
Value of 'null' is not valid for 'stream'... 
Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Pages.PageTemplateHelper.UpdateDefaultTemplateImages(PageManager pageManager, LibrariesManager librariesManager, Album album) at Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Libraries.LibrariesModule.Upgrade(SiteInitializer initializer, Version upgradeFrom) at Telerik.Sitefinity.Services.ModuleBase.Install(SiteInitializer initializer, Version upgradeFrom) at Telerik.Sitefinity.Services.SystemManager.InitializeModuleTelerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Pages.PageTemplateHelper.UpdateDefaultTemplateImages(PageManager pageManager, LibrariesManager librariesManager, Album album) at 
Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Libraries.LibrariesModule.Upgrade
(SiteInitializer initializer, Version upgradeFrom) at Telerik.Sitefinity.Services.ModuleBase
.Install(SiteInitializer initializer, Version upgradeFrom) at Telerik.Sitefinity.Services.SystemManager.InitializeModule
```

It looks the upgrade fails due to a problem with a page template thumbnail.

I suggest you run this SQL script towards the database - it will return all Image records (media content) for the page template thumbnails:

```
select * from sf_media_content as mc
join sf_content_link as cl
on cl.child_item_id = mc.content_id
where parent_item_type = 'Telerik.Sitefinity.Pages.Model.PageTemplate'
```

Have a look at the returned results and see if any of them looks suspicious.

Export the results to csv for easy access.

Then do a database backup.

Then, you can pick one of the images, e.g. one with default_url of: /images/SystemLibrariesProvider/template-thumbnails/mvc_default
and record its content_id, e.g. 78EB6662-F8C9-4A2E-85CA-966898D433F1

Then execute this SQL:

```
update sf_content_link
set child_item_id = '78EB6662-F8C9-4A2E-85CA-966898D433F1'
where parent_item_type = 'Telerik.Sitefinity.Pages.Model.PageTemplate'
```

Then kill the process and start the site.

If that image is good, the upgrade should proceed, if you were not lucky - then pick another content_id from your CSV and run the same update sql script with the new Id.
Restart and repeat until it works.

If all is good - you will end up with all page templates having the same thumbnail, but that's not a critical issue and can be fixed later.

Comment: Was trying the above mentioned steps updating content id. In the UI it got stuck in the same place.

Message: PASSED : Scheduling task to create dependencies for existing MediaContent's changes.
Timestamp: 1/9/2020 1:45:56 PM
Message: PASSED : Set ControlId to existing content locations
Timestamp: 1/9/2020 1:55:26 PM
Message: PASSED : Create dependencies for existing MediaContent's changes

But when i checked the trace logs it passed that stage. But now the CPU for IIS worker process is 0 and at times going to 0.1.  No errors also logged. Waiting hopefully

Comment: if no errors - that's good. if it is stuck - kill the process again and see what happens

Comment: Hi @Veselin, i tried with most of the content id's but now i don't have any errors but its getting stuck always. i even tried running it whole night but nothing seems to help.

Comment: and there is nothing in the UpgradeTrace or Error logs? are you able to go /sitefinity ?

Comment: there is nothing in error log .. in update trace it is logging like : 

Message: PASSED : Set ControlId to existing content locations after that no entry is there. 
Trying to contact sitefinity but while clicking on Technical Support in my account it is showing some provisioning problem with your account. I have mailed in the mail provided in the error screen. Waiting for the response from them

Comment: once trying to build and open the localhost got an error saying some machine key error. Not sure if it has got something to do with this. Attaching that image above. Just in case if that can help.

Comment: I would remove the machinekey from the web.config (it's definitely not part of a standard sitefinity installation).

Comment: removing the machinekey helped. Now its not getting stuck. Site is up with new version even though few errors have been logged. Thank you so much. Your suggestions helped a lot